# How to configure ES6 code inspection

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, pycharm

I've been using PyCharm and really liked it. Recently I switched to ES6 for my javascript code. But PyCharm doesn't seem to like it. For things like `=>` or `let` it will report syntax error. I tried a lot of things like turning off all inspection and all my effort were in vain. I think I must be missing something silly because normally PyCharm is quite intelligent. What's the trick?

PyCharm version: 2016.1

END OF QUESTION

A bit of rant in the end: I'd really like to get this working. As a long time Vim user, I find it hard to configure Vim for dynamic language such as Javascript and keep making silly mistakes that's time consuming. I've tried VSCode and like the default behaviour but the Vim emulation is sh*t. JetBrain products has the *best* Vim emulation ever and to me that's a big selling point.

Comment: Have you considered using WebStorm instead? It is nearly identical to PyCharm and made by the same company, but better suited for JavaScript. It supports the exact same plugins as PyCharm. (Including vim)

Comment: I thought PyCharm professional version (trial atm) have all the Javascript support that WebStorm has?

Comment: @lang2 is right, if you are already using PyCharm, it has what's in WebStorm. I did a webinar for PyCharm on using it for frontend development.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just go to `Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript` and change "JavaScript language version" to `ECMAScript 6`

[image]

Comment: What if some of your files are JSX and others are ECMAScript 6?

Comment: yeaaa from first glance no idea what to do if you're using ES6 + React JSX!  but prioritizing for JSX for now.